# Pyspark dataframe conditional filter and imputation

Tags: pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe `df`

| ID | Total_Count | A | B | C | D | Group | Name | Chain |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 56 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | Apple | Fruits1 |
| 2 | 65 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | Apple | Fruits1 |
| 3 | 72 | 0 | 0 | 30 | 0 | 1 | Banana | Fruits1 |
| 4 | 80 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | Strawberry | Fruits1 |
| 5 | 142 | 58 | 58 | 14 | 12 | 1 | Apple | Fruits1 |
| 6 | 130 | 63 | 50 | 9 | 8 | 1 | Apple | Fruits1 |
| 7 | 145 | 74 | 44 | 17 | 10 | 1 | Apple | Fruits1 |
| 8 | 119 | 54 | 48 | 8 | 9 | 1 | Apple | Fruits1 |
| 11 | 161 | 71 | 63 | 16 | 11 | 1 | Banana | Fruits1 |
| 12 | 124 | 54 | 43 | 19 | 8 | 1 | Banana | Fruits1 |

I want to impute the `A,B,C,D` columns wherever there is 0 in `A,B,C,D` columns(ID 1,2,3,4).

1.) Logic : Average of Groupx`Name`(if available) or Average of Groupx`Chain`(if available) or at Average of Group :

Taking the example to impute `ID` 1,2 for demo:
Post filering for Group `1` and Name `Apple`, Proportion for `ID` 1&2 is obtained as follows( For ID 1 and 2  resp. filtering rows with similar Group as `1` and similar `Name` (Apple)) ,proportion is calculated as `A/Total_Count`, `B/Total_Count` and so on :

| A_PROP | B_PROP | C_PROP | D_PROP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.408451 | 0.408450704 | 0.098592 | 0.084507042 |
| 0.484615 | 0.384615385 | 0.069231 | 0.061538462 |
| 0.510345 | 0.303448276 | 0.117241 | 0.068965517 |
| 0.453782 | 0.403361345 | 0.067227 | 0.075630252 |

2.) Average of the above 4 rows is to be taken (for `ID` 1 & 2 for example).
A,B,C,D in `df2` is calcualted as X_prop_avg*Total_Count.

Expected output (`df2`) :

| ID | Total_Count | A_prop_avg | B_prop_avg | C_prop_avg | D_prop_avg | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 56 | 0.46429811 | 0.37496893 | 0.08807265 | 0.07266032 | 26 | 21 | 5 | 4 |
| 2 | 65 | 0.464298107 | 0.374968927 | 0.088072647 | 0.072660318 | 30 | 24 | 6 | 5 |
| 3 | 72 | 0.43823883 | 0.369039271 | 0.126302344 | 0.066419555 | 32 | 27 | 9 | 5 |
| 4 | 80 | 0.455611681 | 0.372992375 | 0.10081588 | 0.070580064 | 36 | 30 | 8 | 6 |